# Wordpress loop in table won't add more than three rows

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing an agenda page on [my website](http://www.fabriciorosa.com.br/agenda/) where it should be listed in rows future events. Problem is, the loop only shows three rows, even though in the 'showposts' loop parameter it's set on 10.

I've noticed when inspecting the page code that it's in fact looping the other posts, but they're showing with 'display: none' - I have no clue why. This is my code:

```
                <table class="agenda-table" align="center" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <th> Quando </th>
                        <th style="background: #f0f0f0"> </th>
                        <th> Quem </th>
                        <th style="background: #f0f0f0"> </th>
                        <th> Onde </th>
                        <th style="background: #f0f0f0"> </th>
                        <th> O quê </th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        query_posts('cat=7&showposts=10');
                        if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                        $dia = get_post_custom_values('dia');
                        $quem = get_post_custom_values('quem');
                        $link = get_post_custom_values('link');
                    ?>  
                    <tr>
                        <td> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link[0];?>"><?php echo $dia[0]; ?> </a> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link[0];?>"><?php echo $quem[0];?> </a></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link[0];?>"><?php echo get_the_content();?> </a> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link[0];?>"> <?php echo get_the_title();?> </a></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check settings -> reading and see how many posts are set to show. and if you have cache plugin installed please clear cache

Comment: It's set on 10 posts also, and I don't have any cache plugin installed :s

Comment: so try to fetch by query      $args = array('post_type' => 'post','cat'=>7);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 // DO SOMETHING
endwhile;

Comment: done that and it outputs the same error. it's actually looping the other posts, but they're appearing as 'display: none' elements in the DOM

Comment: I found the error and it was actually a javascript function that I've made a long time ago that was conflicting with the table. Thanks for the help though :)